# How can I make fixed elements visible ONLY when their parent elements are visible?

Tags: html, css, z-index, fixed

The site I'm working on has several `div` sections each the width and height of the viewport. They are stacked vertically, each with relative positioning (See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/htunnicliff/pen/acowD/)). Inside each element is a fixed-position `h1`. I'd like for the fixed `h1` in each element to remain visible only when its respective parent is visible.

I've already tried a number of z-index experiments with no success. Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: Use position absolute instead of position fixed on the h1. Does that accomplish what you were looking for?

Comment: Are you lookinf for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aloisdg/5C8jN/1/) ?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think there's a way to determine if an element is within the viewport with pure CSS. If you're open to Javascript or jQuery, I can definitely help you with that

Answer (score 2):

Since a fixed position element is located in the viewport and not the DOM.  Meaning you would need to manipulate the HTML tag making what you would like to do pretty much impossible.

Two options though, first being too change position to absolute (with the adjustments to position being based off closet parent with position of relative, absolute, fixed or the DOM root) and hide the appropriate parent element.

Second option would be to simply hide and show the fixed element using your favorite JS library to respond to user interaction instead of wrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use js to achieve the result. here is the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cHyBo) with jQuery.

```
function showCurrentTitle(){
jQuery('.section h1').hide()
    .each(function(i, el){
        var o = parseInt(jQuery(this).parent().offset().top);
        var h = jQuery(this).height();
        if(o <= jQuery(document).scrollTop() ||
            o + h < jQuery(document).scrollTop() + jQuery(this).height()){
            jQuery(this).show();
        };
    });
}
showCurrentTitle();
jQuery(document).scroll(function(e){
    showCurrentTitle();
});
```